# Oracle: How can I find tablespace fragmentation?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

I've a JOIN beween two tables. It's really really slow and I can't find why.
The query takes hours in a PRODUCTION environment on a very big Client.
Can you ask me what you need to understand why it doesn't work well?
I can add indexes, partition the table, etc. It's Oracle 10g.
I expect a few thousand record. Because of the following condition: 
f.eif_campo1 != c.fornitura AND and f.field29  =  'New'
Infact it should be always verified for all 18 million records

```
  SELECT    c.id_messaggio
           ,f.campo1 
           ,c.f
    FROM   
           flows c, 
           tab f
   WHERE   
               f.field198                  =  c.id_messaggio 
           AND f.extra_id      =  c.extra_id
           and f.field1                    != c.ExampleF
           and f.field29                   =  'New'
           and c.processtype         in ('Example1')
           and c.flag_ann                  =  'N';
```

Selectivity for the following record expressed as number of distinct values:

```
 COUNT (DISTINCT extra_id)                      =>17*10^6, 
 COUNT (DISTINCT (extra_id || field20))    =>17*10^6, 
 COUNT (DISTINCT field198)                                  =>36*10^6, 
 COUNT (DISTINCT (field19 || field20))                =>45*10^6, 
 COUNT (DISTINCT (field1))                                  =>18*10^6, 
 COUNT (DISTINCT (field20))                                =>47
```

This is the execution plan [See large image][1]
![enter image description here][2]

---

**Extra details:**
I have relaxed one contition to see how many records are taken. 300 thousand.

![enter image description here][7]

--03:57 mins with parallel execution /*+ parallel(c 8) parallel(f 24) */

--395.358 rows

```
  SELECT     count(1)
    FROM   
           flows c, 
           flet f
   WHERE   
               f.field19                  =  c.id_messaggio 
           AND f.extra_id      =  c.extra_id
           and f.field20                  =  'ExampleF'
           and c.process_type         in ('ExampleP')
           and c.flag_ann                  =  'N';
```

Comment: How many rows are returned by your query?

Comment: I expect a few thousand record. Because of this condition: f.eif_campo1                    != c.flh_fornitura. Infact it should be always verified for all 18 million records.

Comment: @Gik25: Without that condition, how many rows would you expect?

Comment: @Mark Bannister: 300.000 rows without that condition

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer seems to be your explain plan. You're accessing both tables `by index rowid`. Whilst to select a single row you cannot - to my knowledge - get faster, in your case you're selecting a lot more than a single row.

This means that for every single row you, you're going into both tables one row at a time, which when you're looking a significant proportion of a table or index is not what you want to do.

My suggestion would be to force a `full scan` of one or both of your tables. Try to use the smaller as a driver first:

```
SELECT /*+ full(c) */ c.flh_id_messaggio
     , f.eif_campo1 
     , c.f
  FROM flows c, 
  JOIN flet f
    ON f.field19  =  c.flh_id_messaggio
   AND f.extra_id =  c.extra_id
   AND f.field1 <> c.f
 WHERE ...
```

But you may have to change `/*+ full(c) */` to `/*+ full(c) full(f) */`.

Your indexes seem to be separate column indexes as well. For this, and if possible, I would have indexes on:

- `flows` of `id_messaggio, extra_id, f`
- *and* on `flet` of `field19, extra_id, field1`.

This will only really matter if you do not use as full scan. Or, if you have everything you're returning and selecting is in one index.

Comment: The thing I can't understand is why 300000 access by rowid takes so long. 10 ms for every access it shouldn't take over 40 minutes. What do you think about partitioning? And what about measuring tablespace fragmentation?

Comment: @Gik25, double that ( you've got two tables ). Partitioning, yes, is worth testing for your 180m row table. I don't understand what you mean by tablespace fragmentation. Do you mean table? I would try the simple solution suggested in my answer before doing anything overly final though.

Answer (score 1):

Your explain plan shows the following.

1. The database uses an index to retrieve rows from ENI_FLUSSI_HUB where
   `flh_tipo_processo_cod in ('VT','VOLTURA_ENI','CC')`
2. It then winnows the rows
   where  `flh_flag_ann =  'N'`
3. This produces a result set which is used to access
   rows from ETL_ELAB_INTERF_FLAT on the basis of  `f.idde_identif_dati_ext_id  = 
   c.idde_identif_dati_ext_id`
4. Finally those rows are filtered on the basis of the
   remaining parts of the WHERE clause.

Now, the starting point is a good one if `flh_tipo_processo_cod` is a selective
column: that is, if it contains hundreds of different values, or if the values in
your list are relatively rare.  It might even be a good path of the flag column
identifies relatively few columns with a value of 'N'.   So you need to understand
both the *distribution* of your data - how many distinct values you have - and its
skew - which values appear very often or hardly at all.  The overall
performance suggests that the distribution and/or skew of the
`flh_tipo_processo_cod` and `flh_flag_ann` columns is not good.

So what can you do?  One approach is to follow Ben's suggestion, and use full
table scans.  If you have an Enterprise Edition licence and plenty of CPU capacity
you could try parallel query to improve things.  That might still be too slow, or it might be too disruptive for other users.

An alternative approach would be to use better indexes.  A composite index on
`eni_flussi_hub(flh_tipo_processo_cod,flh_flag_ann,idde_identif_dati_ext_id,
flh_fornitura,flh_id_messaggio)` would avoid the need to read that table.  Whether
this would be a new index or a replacement for ENI_FLK_IDX3 depends on the other
activity against the table.  You might be able to benefit from index compression.

All the columns in the query projection are referenced in the WHERE clause.  So 
you could also use a composite index on the other table to avoid table reads.  Agsin you need to understand the distribution and skew of the data.  But you should probably lead with the least selective columns.  Something like `etl_elab_interf_flat(etl_elab_interf_flat,eif_campo200,dde_identif_dati_ext_id,eif_campo1,eif_campo198)`.  Probably this is a new index.  It's unlikely you would want to replace ETL_EIF_FK_IDX4 with this (especially if that really is an index on a foreign key constraint)..

Of course these are just guesses on my part.  Tuning is a science and to do it properly requires lots of data.  Use [the Wait Interface](http://www.dbspecialists.com/files/presentations/wait_events.html) to investigate where the database is spending its time.  Use [the 10053 event](http://www.centrexcc.com/A%20Look%20under%20the%20Hood%20of%20CBO%20-%20the%2010053%20Event.pdf) to understand why the Optimizer makes the choices it does.  But above all, *don't implement partitioning* unless you really know the ramifications.